# JetBrain Resharper - Move Type to Another File drop down menu not showing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper-8.0

I am following guidelines given at [This location](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Move__Type_to_Another_File.html), this link mentioned that "Move to Another File" option will be displayed, but I did not see it. I am using latest version as -

JetBrains ReSharper 8.2.2 Full Edition
Build 8.2.2000.5102

with visual studio - Visual Studio 10.0.40219.1.

Is there any issue with this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a issue. This happen when the type which we are moving is/are deeply nested within class e.g.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
     class A
     {

         enum B
         {
         }
     }
}
```

. So first, re-factor the code to move that type(enum B) to outer name space(MyNamespace) and then again re-factor it to move required file, you will see menu here. :) :)